# ansible - which file does grouped host look up in group_vars directory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have placed group_name.yml files per groups(/inventory/hosts) in /inventory/group_vars/ directory.
How do I make groups to look up their corresponding var.yml?
Will it get overridden by **/inventory/group_vars/all** if variables are the same?

**/inventory/hosts**

```
[group_1]
host_1
host_2

[group_2]
host_3
host_4
```

**/inventory/group_vars/ directory has**

```
/inventory/group_vars/host_1.yml
/inventory/group_vars/host_2.yml
/inventory/group_vars/host_3.yml
/inventory/group_vars/host_4.yml
```

I want host_1 to reference variables in /inventory/group_vars/host_1.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For host vars use `host_vars` directory, for group vars use `group_vars`.

In your case, valid path's are:

```
/inventory/group_vars/all.yml
/inventory/group_vars/group_1.yml
/inventory/group_vars/group_2.yml
/inventory/host_vars/host_1.yml
/inventory/host_vars/host_2.yml
/inventory/host_vars/host_3.yml
/inventory/host_vars/host_4.yml
```

In different versions of Ansible (if I remember it correctly) vars files were processed in alphabetical order or in order of group nesting, so you'd better try it to be sure. I think in your case, vars from `all.yml` will be applied first, then from `groupN.yml`, then from `hostN.yml`.